JIL: error while loading shared libraries. Libapicom.so: Cannot open shared Object file Error in RedHat
While testing a deployment, we just found this error - while testing our deployment on one of our AutoSys instances. There is:
$ jil: error while loading shared libraries:libapicom.so:cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory.

Already googled around trying to figure this out. Couldnt solve it yet.

Try checking the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. The libapicom.so should reside in $AUTOSYS/lib directory, LD_LIBRARY_PATH should contain the respective path.
